# Using Redux in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, redux

I'm a newbie to Meteor.js and working on a project where I'm also using Redux so I added the [kyutaekang:redux](https://atmospherejs.com/kyutaekang/redux) package. The problem is that I don't know how to import Redux to use it. I tried:

`import { createStore } from 'redux';`,

but when I start the app I get

`[Error: Unable to fetch "redux". Only file URLs of the form file:/// allowed running in Node.]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meteor does not yet support the ES2015 `import` out of the box (might be available in 1.3.0). Therefore, you will need a modern module bundler, as also described in the package's Readme file:

> This assumes that you’re using npm package manager with a module bundler like Webpack or Browserify to consume CommonJS modules.

You can take a look at [this excellent example](https://github.com/AdamBrodzinski/meteor-flux-leaderboard/tree/redux) by Adam Brodzinski to get you started.

**Edit**:

After taking a closer look at the package, it does not seem to contain any code.

Nonetheless, my recommendation about Adam's repo (or his [other repo](https://github.com/AdamBrodzinski/meteor-redux-example), pointed in the comments) still remains as a nice, clean implementation.

Comment: Hi and thanks for replying! I actually installed this `universe:ecmascript` package which "Supports ES2015+ in all .js files with modules", so import keyword was not the problem, but still...  I tried now with `cosmos:browserify` and using `Redux = require('redux');` and now I'm getting `While processing files with cosmos:browserify (for target web.browser): lib/some.browserify.js: Cannot find module 'redux' from '.'`. So both times it seems as if it is looking for redux at a wrong place or something. Have you maybe any idea what it could be?

Comment: After looking at the compiled package source for that particular package, I don't think that it does anything. In the example I linked to, `redux` is loaded using `npm-container`. I loaded `Flux` in a similar way, and configured browserify to load it. Try adding redux using the npm container and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Adam actually made a meteor-redux-example too.  https://github.com/AdamBrodzinski/meteor-redux-example.

Comment: I was actually in the middle of editing this answer. Will add the new link :)